# Rotate image when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, jquery-animate

after using stackoverflow for plenty of help in the past I have a problem which will probably be easy for someone to solve…

I'm trying to rotate a background image when the user scrolls down the page, I have managed to get this far (with help from someone else's question and some helpful answers) but I need to slow down the rotation as its to fast. As far as I can tell I need to do something with the window height and use this to slow the rotation.

Heres my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charliehward/t4MDB/) of how far I've got.

If anyone could help me out I'd be very grateful, my skills aren't quite up to scratch.

My code…

```
$(function() {
var rotation = 0, 
    scrollLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var newLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
    var diff = scrollLoc - newLoc;
    rotation += diff, scrollLoc = newLoc;
    var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
    $(".circle").css({
        "-webkit-transform": rotationStr,
        "-moz-transform": rotationStr,
        "transform": rotationStr
    });
});
})
```

CSS:

```
.container {
width:960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.circleWrap {
margin: 0 auto;
width:960px;
position:relative;
}
.circleContainer {
width: 970px;
position:fixed;
overflow:visible;
z-index:-50;
}
.circle{
background:url('http://www.wearerevolting.co.uk/dev/spin/moodring-col.jpg') no-repeat center;
width: 1772px;
height: 1772px;
margin-left: -400px;
}
.text {
z-index:50;
position:absolute;
height:2000px;
width:960px;
border:#000 thick solid;
}


<div class="container">
    <div class="text">Content area</div>
</div>

<div class="circleWrap">
    <div class="circleContainer">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
```

to

```
var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation / 100 + "deg)";
```

where `100` is an arbitrary limiting value. [**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/t4MDB/2/)